# Perl regex is not giving the expected result

Tags: regex, perl

I have following code

```
  my $string = 'ban-3.1.2278-1.x86_64.1.rpm';
  my ($substr) = ($string =~ /(.+)-\d(.+)/);
  print "Result: $substr\n";
```

I was expecting it to return ban but its returning ban-3.1.2278, I am not able to figure it out why. 
Can anyone please explain me why its behaving it this way and whats the correct way to do it ?

thank you.

Comment: You could [`slice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) it also. E.g., `my $string = (split /-/, 'ban-3.1.2278-1.x86_64.1.rpm')[0];`

Answer (score 2):

Because the any character `.` will match dashes.

If you want to limit he matching, use a characters class or non-greedy matching `.*?`:

```
my $string = 'ban-3.1.2278-1.x86_64.1.rpm';
my ($substr) = $string =~ /([^-]*)-\d(.+)/;
print "Result: $substr\n";
```

Outputs:

```
Result: ban
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make  `.+` inside the first capturing group as non-greedy by adding a  quantifier `?` after `+` so that it would do a reluctant match(ie, shortest possible match) or otherwise it would do  a longest match.

```
(.+?)-\d(.+)
```

Code:

```
my $string = 'ban-3.1.2278-1.x86_64.1.rpm';
my ($substr) = ($string =~ /(.+?)-\d(.+)/);
print "Result: $substr\n";
```

Output:

```
Result: ban
```

Answer (score 1):

Split also gives what you expect. try this

```
my $string = 'ban-3.1.2278-1.x86_64.1.rpm';
my @substr = split('-',$string);
print "Result: $substr[0]\n";
```

Output

```
Result: ban
```

This script is split by the `-` the which is store into the array. Then print the ban by using index key value like `$substr[0]`

Answer (score 0):

In the above code "my ($substr) = ($string =~ /(.+?)-\d(.+)/);", unnecessary grouping are used. Use the following code instead of that,

```
my $string = 'ban-3.1.2278-1.x86_64.1.rpm'; 
$string =~ /([a-z]+)-/i; 
print "Result: $1";
```

If you need an answer only "ban" means use this code.

**[a-z]+**  - it matches more than one continuous alphabet characters(accurate matches).

**i**       - it used for case sensitive.

**$1**      - it returns the value of first grouping.

**OUTPUT**

```
Result: ban
```